# Spherical Trigonometry: RA-Dec to Alt/AZ

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-trigonometry

While this question is related to astronomy, I believe it's a spherical trigonometry problem as outlined below.

Below are two different sets of equations for computing the Altitude and Azimuth of a given point in Right Ascension and Declincation (e.g. a star).  When using the second set of equations, I always get the correct answer (verified with NASA JPL Horizons).  When using the first set of equations, I get the right answer for $a$.  The second equation in the first set, usually gives the right answer, unless $h$ is negative, and the first equation only occasionally gives the right answer.

Both sets of equations appear similarly in many computational astronomy books.  In the book "**3D Astronomy with Java**", the author derives the first set using spherical trigonometry.  In the book "**Fundamental Astronomy** by Karttunen et al", they state that both the cos and sin of $A_z$ are needed to determine the correct quadrant.  And in the "**Nautical Almanac**" the reduction procedures test if $h$ is negative and subtract it from 90, but that doesn't produce the right answer for me.  The equations are as they appear in "**The Explanatory Supplement to the Nautical Almanac 3rd Ed**".

So, my question is:

> How would one use the first set of equations?

$a$ is altitude, $A_z$ is azimuth, $h$ is the hour angle, $\delta$ is the declination, $\phi$ is the latitude.  I did modify the second set of equations to use the same variables at first, so there's possibly a transcription error, just know that they are only included for completeness.

First Set:

$
\cos \mathit{a} \sin A_{z} = -\cos \delta \sin \mathit{h}
\\
\cos \mathit{a} \cos A_{z} = \sin \delta \cos \phi - \cos \delta \cos \mathit{h} \sin \phi
\\
\sin \mathit{a} = \sin \delta \sin \phi + \cos \delta \cos \mathit{h} \cos \phi
$

Second set:

$
\tan A_z = \frac{\sin a}{\cos h \sin \phi  - \tan \delta \cos \phi} \\
\sin a = \sin \phi \sin \delta + \cos \phi \cos \delta \cos h
$

Implementation of the first set:

```
a=Math.asin(Math.sin(dec)*Math.sin(lat)+Math.cos(dec)*Math.cos(H)*Math.cos(lat));
az=Math.acos((Math.sin(dec)*Math.cos(lat)-Math.cos(dec)*Math.cos(H)*Math.sin(lat))/(Math.cos(a)));
az=Math.asin((-Math.cos(dec)*Math.sin(H))/(Math.cos(a)));
```

Implementation of the second set:

```
az = (Math.atan2(Math.sin(H), Math.cos(H)*Math.sin(lat) - Math.tan(dec)*Math.cos(lat)));
a = (Math.asin(Math.sin(lat)*Math.sin(dec) + Math.cos(lat)*Math.cos(dec)*Math.cos(H)));
az-=Math.PI;  //This version produces Az measured from the South, subtract 180
```

Comment: *"The second equation in the first set, usually gives the right answer, unless $h$ is negative, and the first equation only occasionally gives the right answer."* Please be specific about what the kinds of not-right answers you get. Are they merely in the wrong quadrant and/or complementary to correct values, or are they numeric garbage? Can you clarify what "occasionally" means? ... Also, *"the reduction procedures test if $h$ is negative and subtract it from $90$"* To be clear: If $h=-20^\circ$, do we substitute $h=90^\circ-(-20^\circ)=110^\circ$, or $h=90^\circ-20^\circ=70^\circ$?

Comment: Your comment to the `az-=Math.PI;` line of the "implementation of the second set" says `subtract 90 de[grees?]`. But $\pi$ corresponds to $180^\circ$. What's up with that? ... Also the second equation in "implementation of the first set" has a `cos(lat)` in both terms; the second term should have `sin(lat)` (this would match with the earlier MathJax rendering, and it would make the sum of the squares of the three values in that first set equal $1$).

Comment: I fixed the comment to say -180 and the offending "cos(lat)" in the question.  I'm guessing your first comment is correct.  How do I determine what the correct quadrant is?

Comment: And to address your question about the Nautical Almanac procedures, unfortunately the steps aren't written as math equations, so it's rather difficult to equate the two.   My assumption is that the solution involves using all three equations (otherwise why are there three?), and using the sign of the $sin A_z$ and $cos A_z$ values, I would apply some transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error, I have figured it out.  I have labeled the equations below.  The solution depends on the signs of $\cos A_z$ and $\sin A_z$.

if $\cos A_z$ > 0 and $\sin A_z$ > 0: eq1 and eq2 are correct

if $\cos A_z$ > 0 and $\sin A_z$ < 0: eq1 is correct

if $\cos A_z$ < 0 and $\sin A_z$ < 0: $A_z$ = 360 - eq2

if $\cos A_z$ < 0 and $\sin A_z$ > 0: eq2 is correct

$
\textbf eq1 \cos \mathit{a} \sin A_{z} = -\cos \delta \sin \mathit{h}
\\
\textbf eq2 \cos \mathit{a} \cos A_{z} = \sin \delta \cos \phi - \cos \delta \cos \mathit{h} \sin \phi
\\
\textbf eq3 \sin \mathit{a} = \sin \delta \sin \phi + \cos \delta \cos \mathit{h} \cos \phi
$